# Any suggestions how can I optimize this code? I need to translate some strings in 3 languages. Thanks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, wpml

Changing strings depending on language. Is there a better solution to translate strings? Is there a way to shorten the code. Thanks.

```
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'cart_page_notice' );
 
function cart_page_notice() {
    $min_amount = 1000; //This is the amount of your free shipping threshold. Change according to your free shipping settings
    $current = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if (( $current < $min_amount ) && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ru') {
    $added_text = '<div class="woocommerce-message"><strong>Купите еще на ' . wc_price( $min_amount - $current ) . ' для бесплатной доставки</strong>'; // This is the message shown on the cart page
    $return_to = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ru'){  
    $notice = sprintf( '%s<a class="button" href="%s">%s</a>', $added_text, esc_url( $return_to ), 'Продолжить покупки</div>' ); // This is the text shown below the notification. Link redirects to the shop page
        echo $notice;
    }
    }if (( $current < $min_amount ) && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') {
    $added_text = '<div class="woocommerce-message"><strong>Buy ' . wc_price( $min_amount - $current ) . ' worth products more to get free shipping</strong>'; // This is the message shown on the cart page
    $return_to = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'){  
    $notice = sprintf( '%s<a class="button" href="%s">%s</a>', $added_text, esc_url( $return_to ), 'Continue shopping</div>' ); // This is the text shown below the notification. Link redirects to the shop page
    }
        echo $notice;
    }elseif (( $current < $min_amount ) && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'tr') {
    $added_text = '<div class="woocommerce-message"><strong>Ücretsiz kargo için ' . wc_price( $min_amount - $current ) . ' daha satın alın</strong>'; // This is the message shown on the cart page
    $return_to = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'tr'){  
    $notice = sprintf( '%s<a class="button" href="%s">%s</a>', $added_text, esc_url( $return_to ), 'Alışverişe devam</div>' ); // This is the text shown below the notification. Link redirects to the shop page
    }
    echo $notice;
}
}
```

Comment: Ask this question at [codereview.SE]

Answer (score 1):

You could use variables to assign the language text in a `switch` statement to reduce the repitition of your current code:

```
switch(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) {
        case 'ru':
            $buyText = 'Купите еще на %s для бесплатной доставки';
            $continueText = 'Продолжить покупки';
        break;
        case 'tr':
            $buyText = 'Ücretsiz kargo için %s daha satın alın';
            $continueText = 'Alışverişe devam';
        break;
        default: //en
            $buyText = 'Buy %s worth products more to get free shipping';
            $continueText = 'Continue shopping';
        break;
    
    }
$buyText = sprintf($buyText, wc_price( $min_amount - $current ) );
```

You can then get rid of the `if` statements to output a single piece of code based on the variables above:

```
if (( $current < $min_amount )) {
        $buyText = sprintf($buyText, $min_amount - $current );
        $added_text = '<div class="woocommerce-message"><strong>'.$buyText.'</strong>'; // This is the message shown on the cart page
        $return_to = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
    
        $notice = sprintf( '%s<a class="button" href="%s">%s</a>', $added_text, esc_url( $return_to ), $continueText ); // This is the text shown below the notification. Link redirects to the shop page
        echo $notice;
    }
```

Here a slimmed down example with the wp specific functions removed so it will run in vanilla PHP: https://3v4l.org/C9MCJ